# Dell laptop not turning on and charging suddenly in middle of my usage

Tags: laptop, battery, power, dell-inspiron, lcd

I'm using dell inspiron laptop without bezel and lcd screen stands in support of lcd back cover only. I typically use my laptop sideways on bed so I could lay down and watch.
This time while I'm using it, lcd screen drop down towards my face and it's got unplugged video cable, not wholly but partially. I didn't know whether my laptop is turned on after that since my display was not there at that time. Then I plugged the video cable back, display is not coming and then i tried to turn on my laptop, it's not turning on. I tried to charge it but it's not charging.

One year back only I replaced charging port, one year back only I replaced with non branded lcd screen.

It was working fine till date. I don't know just because lcd screen dropped down from back cover towards me and got unplugged causes this issue.

I turn off laptop by removing battery and press hold power button for 1min and put back the battery and checked. Still laptop not turning on and also not charging.

What to do? Now I removed battery, hard disk, ssd. I tried plugging the other laptop working  charger - it's not working. I tried this laptop charger in other laptop - charger is in working condition only. I try plugging charger without battery in laptop - still not working.

What to do to debug this issue? What may caused this issue? Its weird that while I'm using it display unplug causes laptop to turn off? Or maybe laptop battery power dropped suddenly? See the pic below I kept laptop like this and I don't know what to do now.

[image: Laptop Image]